# How can I git pull and git checkout correctly?

Tags: git

I'm working on a build that currently does the following:

After the git repo has been initialized and pulled down to a specific revision, I need to pull down a commit that is further in time, apply, and then build.

Currently, the commands I'm running in my build script are:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
git checkout [ID I want]
git submodule update
[Build command]
```

However, when I run this twice, I get "Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected! Assume -R? [n]" on many of the files. I can add a "git reset --hard HEAD^" as the first line, but I'd rather not have to rebuild the entire project each time from scratch.

Is there a good way to allow the build command to run without having to rebuild everything and also not get the reversed patch detected message?

Comment: `git reset --hard` won’t cause your thing to have to be rebuilded; at least not more than another checkout would. A hard reset will only replace the tracked files, so only source files that are within Git. Binaries etc. won’t be deleted. – In general, you want to avoid using `git pull` in a automated build process because a pull is always a merge and a merge can cause conflicts which can fail and may need user interaction.

Comment: Doing just git reset --hard doesn't fix the patch detected error. When I reset --hard HEAD^ before the checkout, the make then thinks the source files have changed, and rebuilds all of them.

Comment: Oh, I see. You could try `git reset --soft HEAD~1` to reset the branch pointer, and then `git checkout -- .` at the working directory root to check out the changed files.

Comment: Ah! That seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if you need a hard reset but want to avoid checking out all files as `git reset --hard` does, resetting the modified timestamps of each file, then you can do a soft reset followed by a file checkout:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
git checkout -- .
```

The file checkout makes sure to only checkout those files that were changed, while the soft reset still resets the branch pointer to the target commit.